# why when running project on another computer restore is needed?

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget

I use .net core 2.2 on an offline computer with nuget.config which includes `globalPackageFolder=".\packages"`.
My restore nuget is disabled. I reference the dlls and run the project, everything is OK. 
When I pass the code to another developer, the VS2019 can't find the referenced dlls even so the packages folder is on the same location as mine.
Why?

Comment: Does the folder contain all the DLLs? Are they blocked (a very common issue when DLLs are sent over the network)? Either of these could cause VS not to find them.

Comment: I found out that there is an assets json file in obj folder. i added packages location for nuget restore if assets.json is not poiting to the right location. the question is if I can totally avoid restore of nugets?